# How to get the current time in tm struct in c++?

Tags: c++

What functions can I use to get the local time in a `tm` struct, which I can then pass to the `_mkgmtime()` function?

I tried using an example from cppreference, but the `localtime()` function is considered insecure, and the program won't compile because of that.

Comment: try `localtime_r` or `localtime_s`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime

Comment: Which compiler and settings are you using which considers that insecure?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Those are functions added in C11 (`localtime_s`) and C23 (`localtime_r`). I don't see anything saying that they're available in any C++ standard.

Comment: @Kevin yep, but most c++ compilers offer a c standard library too, the OP is likely using MSVC which provides `localtime_s`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/localtime-s-localtime32-s-localtime64-s?view=msvc-170

Comment: @Kevin The C++ standard does not consider `localtime` insecure either. So we are, by necessity, talking about things that are not in the standard.

Comment: You can disable the "insecure" warnings/errors by defining a macro. The error message should tell you which one.

Comment: A compiler that refuses to compile code because it uses `localtime()` does not conform to the C language definition. You're compiling with some non-conforming setting, like "refuse to compile code that produces any warnings". Some folks like to do that, but it leads to all sorts of mysterious problems because the "validity" of the code depends on the compiler writer's notion of what's good form.

Comment: `_mkgmtime` is not a standard function, either. Also, something to be aware of is that `_mkgmtime` expects a `tm` in UTC time, not local time.  So, you would need to use  `gmtime(_r|_s)` instead.

Comment: @PeteBecker "it leads to all sorts of mysterious problems" no it doesn't. A compiler that notices a problem in my code that another compiler misses is not a problem, it is a solution.

Comment: If your goal is to generate a `std::time_t` with the current time, why not get the current time into a `std::chrono::time_point` and then use `std::chrono::to_time_t`? https://godbolt.org/z/eb3Ex33cq

Comment: @n.m. -- code whose meaning is well defined and does what was intended but violates some compiler developer's style guidelines isn't a problem in your code. The problem arises when you feel you have to spend time tracking it down and rewriting the code in some non-obvious manner in order to make the compiler happy.

Comment: @PeteBecker Perhaps you know when code meaning is well defined just by looking at it, but I am not as good, so I need all the help I can get. Warnings help so I use them. A false positive now and then is not a problem, I fix it and move on.

Comment: @n.m. correctly using of [`std::localtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) isn’t that hard. How would you “fix” it?

Comment: @PeteBecker This function is not thread-safe. You decide if this makes it hard or impossible to use correctly.